# How do I display Pods data for a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, podscms, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm experimenting with the Pods plugin for wordpress.

I've created a Custom Post Type with pods. My next step is to create a single-[cptname].php. I might also want to create custom Page Template that access the user-created data associated with a Pods CPT.

How do I access the data entered by a user for a Pods Custom Post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom post type Pod uses the default meta storage, then you can use `get_post_meta()` to get the custom field values. We did a PodsCast on this topic recently: http://pods.io/2015/04/03/podscast-003-displaying-data-in-pods-pt-1/

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Just found Pods, love it, looking forward to repeatable fields!